# Sitecore fetching duplicate data from Salesforce end when using DEF 3.0.0

Tags: data-exchange-framework

I am using Sitecore 9.2 and DEF 3.0.0.

I am facing a weird problem when fetching data from Salesforce. The `ReadObjectStepProcessor` of DEF is using *ObjectReader* class that fetch data from the Salesforce end. The problem is when fetching more than 2000 records, it's duplicating the existing records. The dataset count in Salesforce is 264868. The First 2000 records are distinct but from 2001 records it again fetches the first 2000 records. I want to push data to the SQL database from the Salesforce end.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar issue with the standard Salesforce Provider and DEF 2.0.1. It turned out there was an endless loop in the method `ReadObjects()` of class `Sitecore.DataExchange.Providers.Salesforce.ReadObjects.ObjectReader`.

We fixed it by overriding classes `ObjectReader` and `ReadObjectsStepProcessor`. You may need to adapt the code below to work with DEF 3.0.0, but the principle is the same.

Please note the last line `result = Task.Run<>...` - this is what was missing from the original method.

```
public class CustomObjectReader : Sitecore.DataExchange.Providers.Salesforce.ReadObjects.ObjectReader
{
    public override IEnumerable<ExpandoObject> ReadObjects(ForceClient client, ObjectReaderContext context)
    {
        if (client == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(client));
        if (context == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        string soql = this.GetSoqlStatement(context);
        QueryResult<ExpandoObject> result = Task.Run(() => client.QueryAsync<ExpandoObject>(soql)).Result;
        while (result != null)
        {
            foreach (ExpandoObject record in result.Records)
                yield return record;
            if (result.Done || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(result.NextRecordsUrl))
                break;
            result = Task.Run(() => client.QueryContinuationAsync<ExpandoObject>(result.NextRecordsUrl)).Result;
        }
    }
}
```

After this you will need to override the class `ReadObjectsStepProcessor` and use your newly created `CustomObjectReader`

```
public class CustomReadObjectsStepProcessor : Sitecore.DataExchange.Providers.Salesforce.ReadObjects.ReadObjectsStepProcessor
{
    private readonly CustomObjectReader customObjectReader =  new CustomObjectReader();

    protected override IObjectReader GetObjectReader(Endpoint endpoint, PipelineStep pipelineStep, PipelineContext pipelineContext, ILogger logger)
    {
        return customObjectReader;
    }
}
```

The final step is to reference CustomReadObjectsStepProcessor in the pipeline step. Open your `Read Salesforce Objects Pipeline Step` and replace `Processor Type` field value with the custom processor class:

```
Namespace.CustomReadObjectsStepProcessor, AssemblyName
```

Comment: Hey Anna, thanks for the reply, but I fixed it already that day 

Comment: @StanLee was it the same issue with an endless loop?

Comment: Yeah same issue with endless loop. Its running infinitely when I am hitting Run Pipeline Batch